# String pattern searching

Tags: linux, grep

I'm new to linux. I want to be placed as a System Admin. I attended an interview at Amazon. They asked me to write a cmd to find the string that starts with 's' and ends with 'a' in a file. I know that we have to use grep, but I don't know how to use it. Added to this they also asked how grep works. Can anyone brief out an answer for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: look into Regular Expressions (regex) http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm and the way awk uses them in linux: http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html

Comment: What have you tried? You should first try [Google](https://www.google.com), read up on `grep`, and if you *still* have a problem, ask here (and include what you have tried).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man pages are the most helpful.  They take some time to read through, however as a budding sysadmin (congrats!) it will behoove you to start being able to navigate and understand man pages

Many man pages are on the internet, so you can google search "grep man page" and find one

Here is one I found

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html

In the man page a little over halfway down you will see a discussion of "REGULAR EXPRESSIONS".  The above command does not require anything tricky in the way of regular expressions, you just want a regular expression to match a character at the beginning of the string and at the end of the string

Good luck!